# WPF resize issue

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

I am new to using wpf having used windows forms for a while. I am attempting to create a simple UI that resizes based on the screen size. However when I run the application it normally just cuts part of the screen off. In this case the 'lower_Border' must fill the remaining space and resize its internal contents, I can't get it to do this.
I have attached the code below.
Thanks in advance

```
<UserControl x:Name="User_MainTemplate" x:Class="EventsUnlimited.UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EventsUnlimited"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" d:DesignWidth="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}">
<Grid Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"  Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" Background="#FF1291DA" />
    <Border x:Name="lower_Border"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF143199" >
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1133" >
            <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="937"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1872" >
                <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
                <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>

    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: For this kind of ordering I usually use a Dock Panel: https://wpftutorial.net/DockPanel.html It is what we used for that "Office Application design" since back in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

You have the second `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />` and it needs to be set to star `<RowDefinition Height="*" />`.  Auto will adjust it to fit the content, star will adjust it to fill.

Comment: I think I understand. auto sizes the grid to the size of the element and * uses all available space? So to resize the content would you use a viewbox? Thanks

Comment: No, a ViewBox is for scaling content to a specific size and maintaining aspect.  Much like you can set the size of Font when you place objects in ViewBox they grow / shrink to the size of the ViewBox.

Comment: I think the issue was that the content wasn't scaling to the correct size e.g. the tab control wasn't changing to stay inside the bounds of the border. Adding a viewbox fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

On your tab control, you are giving height an explicit value of 937, try removing Height=937

Comment: I tried that, however when removed it sets the height to the area that has something in it. However I need it to take up a set area of the screen even when empty.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I was mistaken about the grid. The grid will resize the space between the elements.

To resize the element itself you must use a virtual box and put the element inside it.